# Add new property based on a different objects property

Tags: arrays, regex, parsing, powershell

I'm trying to search through one column in each row of the table. I would then like to add another value to the row based on the number being search.

This code produces the table:

```
$LUNSSummary = ($NY_LUNS)  -split '\s+(?=LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER)' | foreach {
    $Stringdata = $_.replace(':','=')
    New-Object PSObject -Property $(ConvertFrom-StringData $Stringdata)
}

$LUNSSummary |
    select 'Name','LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER','State','LUN Capacity(Megabytes)','LU Storage Groups' |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

[image]

Then I have this code which can search using the "Logical Unit Number" and produce the desired output. In this example the -contains is 1029 from the above screenshot.

```
$data = $LUNS_in_Pools | Out-String
$pools = $data -replace ': +','=' -split "`r`n`r`n" |
  % { New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property (ConvertFrom-StringData $_) } |
  select -Property *,@{n='LUNs';e={$_.LUNs -split ', '}} -Exclude LUNs

$pools | ? { $_.LUNs -contains 1029 } | select -Expand 'Pool Name'
```

Which produces in this case "Pool 2". The result can be Pool 1-99.

[image]

I want to combine these two codes to search every "Logical Unit Number" and add the result to the end of the table in a 5th section/column "Pools".

**EDIT**

As requested, raw data:

- `$NY_LUNS` before `$LUNSSummary` gets it: http://pastebin.com/5wrd51Lf
- `$LUNS_in_Pools` raw data: http://pastebin.com/Zg9q6jhe

Desired Output: (Pool is obtained from "Logical Unit Number")
[image]

**EDIT 2**

This is now the closest to correct so far, it prints the same pool result every time.

```
$LUNSSummary = 
($NY_LUNS)  -split '\s+(?=LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER)' | 
foreach { $Stringdata = 
          $_.replace(':','=')
          New-Object PSObject -Property  $(ConvertFrom-StringData $Stringdata)
} 

$data = $LUNS_in_Pools | Out-String
$pools = $data -replace ': +','=' -split "`r`n`r`n" |
  % { New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property (ConvertFrom-StringData $_) } |
  select -Property *,@{n='LUNs';e={$_.LUNs -split ', '}} -Exclude LUNs

$poolProperty = @{Label="Pool";Expression={$pools | ? { $_.LUNs -contains       [int]$_.'LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER'} | select -Expand 'Pool Name'}}
$LUNSSummary | select 'Name','LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER','State','LUN      Capacity(Megabytes)','LU Storage Groups',$poolProperty
```

if I check the output of `$pools | ? { $_.LUNs -contains       [int]$_.'LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER'} | select -Expand 'Pool Name'`

I only see one result. I'm thinking maybe it has to be looped some how?

Comment: Can you post some real raw data as text in your question, in particular the relevant columns of data in `LUNS_in_Pools`. And importantly a sample of the desired output.

Comment: Appreciated. And a sample of the desired output so we know what we're aiming for?

Comment: @Kev No problem. Added desired output as well.

Comment: Sounds like you just need one more calculated expression to match that up for you. You have already done the work. You are just matching the `Logical Unit Number` to its associated result in `$pools`?

Comment: Thats right, and then adding it to the end of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the guess of it you just need one more calculated property on the end there for 'Pool'. You already have, and tested, the logic. Just need to implement it.

```
$poolProperty = @{Label="Pool";Expression={
    $lunID = $_.'LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER';
    $pools | Where-Object{$_.LUNs -contains $lunID} | 
        Select-Object -Expand 'Pool Name'}
}
$LUNSSummary | select 'Name','LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER','State','LUN Capacity(Megabytes)','LU Storage Groups',$poolProperty
```

We take the `LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER` of the current item in the pipeline and save it so that we can start another to extract the match from the `$pools` object. As long as you `luns` are exclusive this would always return one `Pool Name`.

The above should work but I changed how `$pools` was created so it matched the logic of `$LUNSSummary`. I used here-strings for the raw data from your paste bin.

```
$LUNSSummary = ($NY_LUNS)  -split '\s+(?=LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER)' | 
foreach { $Stringdata = 
          $_.replace(':','=')
          New-Object PSObject -Property  $(ConvertFrom-StringData $Stringdata)
} 

$pools = ($LUNS_in_Pools | Out-String) -split '\s+(?=Pool Name)' | ForEach-Object{
    New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property (ConvertFrom-StringData ($_ -replace ":","=")) |
    Select -Property *,@{n='LUNs';e={$_.LUNs -split ',\s*'}} -Exclude LUNs
}

$poolProperty = @{Label="Pool";Expression={
    $lunID = $_.'LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER';
    $pools | Where-Object{$_.LUNs -contains $lunID} | 
        Select-Object -Expand 'Pool Name'}
}
$LUNSSummary | select 'Name','LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER','State','LUN Capacity(Megabytes)','LU Storage Groups',$poolProperty
```

Looks like `$LUNS_in_Pools` was a newline delimited string. Piping to `Out-String` cleaned it up to remove the newlines and allow the `regex`/`ConvertFrom-StringData` to work.

Comment: This is producing a Pool column but they are all blank. Is this maybe because $pools does not contain the "Logical Unit Number" column, $NY_LUNS does.

Comment: I believe this would work if $LUNSSummary included the information from $pools in each split. I could be way off though.

Comment: @RichT I'm close. Just rebuilding your environment now.. Will post soon. Something is wrong with $pools.

Comment: Actually that assumption seems wrong....... test and let me know. I did have it working with that code above.

Comment: I'm still getting blank entries for Pool.

Here is the output for $poolProperty
http://pastebin.com/MNF73D6L .

And here is the output for $pools with your edits, seems like more spacing, don't know if that matters.
http://pastebin.com/ZWX8bg8a .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81037/discussion-between-matt-and-richt).

Comment: I added some new details from out findings Matt